# Post On Face Book Wall using asp.net using Facebook c# sdk or javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to post on Facebook wall using Facebook c# sdk and mvc or asp.net web forms are welcomed it will not be different and there is java script sdk  is it will be good or using Facebook c# sdk is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use javascript with server side code no need for facebook c# sdk if your case do not need a lot of work and cases :

you can create a user control like this :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FacebookShare.ascx.cs"
Inherits="FacebookApplication.Controls.FacebookShare" %>
<div>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
    <div onclick="return shareWithFacebook();" style="border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: #d3dde5;
        padding: 5pt; width: 175pt; cursor: pointer;">
        <img src='http://www.codeproject.com/images/fb_share.gif' border="0"
 alt="facebook likeus" style="vertical-align: middle;
            padding-right: 5pt;" />
        <strong>Share with Facebook</strong>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({ appId: '<%= ApplicationId %>', status: true, cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });
        };
        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        } ());

        function shareWithFacebook() {
            FB.ui({ method: 'stream.publish',
                message: '<%= Message %>',
                user_message_prompt: '<%= Prompt %>',
                attachment: {
                    name: '<%= Name %>',
                    caption: '<%= Caption %>',
                    description: ('<%= Description %>'),
                    href: '<%= Href %>',
                    media: [{ 'type': 'image', 'src': '<%= Image %>',
   'href': '<%= Href %>'}]
                },
                action_links: [
                { text: '<%= Name %>', href: '<%= Href %>' }
            ]
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    // Do some custom action after the user successfully
    // posts this to their wall
                    alert('Thanks for sharing!');
                }
            }
        );
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

the code behind :

```
namespace FacebookApplication.Controls
{
    public partial class FacebookShare : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Prompt { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and withing you aspx page :

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
 AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="FacebookApplication._Default" %>

<%@ Register src="Controls/FacebookShare.ascx" tagname="FacebookShare"
 tagprefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src=http://www.codeproject.com/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js
 type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        A customizable Facebook Share button
    </h2>
    <p>
        <uc1:FacebookShare ID="FacebookShare1" runat="server"
  ApplicationId="12345" Message="Message"
            Name="Name" Caption="Caption" Description="Description"
  Href="http://mourfield.com"
            Image="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/41e139e92663400389c2c9d95a865820.png" />
  </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/"
            title="Facebook Developer Docs">documentation on Facebook at
  Facebook Developers</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

ten you can set you properties within the page on page load event